# Node.js event loop latency testing

Tags: node.js, benchmarking, v8, percentile, libuv

I measure nodejs event loop using [process.hrtime()](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime) also I count [percentiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) for measuring intervals. 
Here is my simple benchmark [example](https://github.com/korzhev/latency_test)

I have run this test on PC with CPU i7-4770.

This is how graph looks like when script runs on **Windows 7**(same type of graph is on OSX):
[image: windows 7]
***Asix X***(horizontal) - time. ***Asix Y***(vertical) - 90th percentile latency in **μs** (microseconds)

And this is how graph looks like when script runs on **CentOS 7/6**:
[image]
***Asix X***(horizontal) - time. ***Asix Y***(vertical) - 90th percentile latency in **μs** (microseconds). Wavelength is about 2 minutes.

As you can see, in general latency on linux is bigger than on windows. But real problem is periodic peaks, when average latency and number of high latency are increasing.

I`m not sure is this OS, v8 or libuv issue. Is there any good explanation of this behavior? Or how can it be fixed?